# Post data to api via curl

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I trying to post some data to an api but i having problem on that(the page only loading after i submit the request)

My request.php

```
$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://example/epayment/xxx.asp");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELD,json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                                      
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                            
    'Content-Length:'.strlen(json_encode($data)))                                                                                   
 );
$return=curl_exec($ch);
echo $return;
curl_close($ch);
```

Expectation:
After submit the request, the api will redirect the page from request.php to response.php . 

P.S :New to curl and sry for bad english

Comment: Curl itself can redirect, but if you want to redirect the request.php file use header('Location: '.$newURL);

Comment: Incidentally it ought to be `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` rather than `CURLOPT_POSTFIELD` I believe. Is `response.php` supposed to process the actual response in some way?

Answer (score 3):

The remote API won't redirect your client, but you should do it:

```
$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://example/epayment/xxx.asp");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELD,json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                                      
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                            
    'Content-Length:'.strlen(json_encode($data)))                                                                                   
 );
$return=curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
//echo $return;
curl_close($ch);
if ($err) {
    echo $err;   
} else {
    header('Location: response.php');
    exit();
}
```